# On the definition of Universes.

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

The following is a definition on page 10 in the book of Catefories and sheaves by Masaki Kashiwara and Pierre Schapira.

**Definition1.1.1.** A universe $\mathcal U $ is a set satisfying the following properties:

(i) $\emptyset \in \mathcal U$,

(ii) $u \in \mathcal U $ implies $u \subset \mathcal U$, (equivalently, $x \in \mathcal U$ and $ y\in x $ implies $y \in \mathcal U$, or else $\mathcal U \subset \mathcal{P(U)})$,

(iii) $u \in \mathcal U$ implies $\{u\}\in \mathcal U$,

(iv)  $u \in \mathcal U$ implies $\mathcal{P(u)}\in \mathcal U$,

(v) if $I \in \mathcal U$ and $u_i \in \mathcal U$ for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I} u_i \in \mathcal U$,

(vi) $\mathbb N \in \mathcal U$.

As a consequence we have

(vii) $u\in \mathcal U$ implies $\bigcup_{x\in u} x \in \mathcal U$,

(viii) $u, v \in \mathcal U$ implies $u \times v \in \mathcal U$,

(ix) $u \subset v \in \mathcal U$ implies $u \in \mathcal U$,

(x) if $I \in \mathcal U$ and $u_i \in \mathcal U$ for all $i \in I $, then $\prod_{i \in I}u_i \in \mathcal U$.

**My Question**

1) In (ii), I proved that "$u \in \mathcal U $ implies $u \subset \mathcal U$" if and only if" $x \in \mathcal U$ and $ y\in x $ implies $y \in \mathcal U$" 
but I don't understand what is intended by the condition of $\mathcal U \subset \mathcal{P(U)}$.

2) (i),$\dots$,(vi) implies (vii),$\dots$, (x), right? Then how to induce (viii) and (x) by the former?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear... (ii) is part of a def; do you mean: prove that the two statements in (ii) are equivalent ?

Comment: For 1, if that's a direct quote it's awkwardly worded, but it is just saying a third way of stating condition (ii) is simply $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U})$ which is equivalent to $\forall u \in \mathcal{U}.u\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U})$ which is equivalent to $\forall u \in \mathcal{U}.u\subseteq\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: $\mathcal P (\mathcal U)$ is the power-set of $\mathcal U$, i.e. the set of **all** subsets of $\mathcal U$.

Comment: $\mathcal U$ is a subset of itself; thus $\mathcal U \in \mathcal P(\mathcal U)$.

Comment: Thus, applying (ii), we have that: for all $x$, if $x \in \mathcal U$, then $x \subseteq \mathcal U$. But $x \subseteq \mathcal U$ is equiv to $x \in \mathcal P(\mathcal U)$.

Comment: Then we apply the def of subset: $A \subseteq B$ **iff**: for all $x$, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, to conclude with: $\mathcal U \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathcal U)$.

Comment: (vii) is nothing more than (v) with $u$ in place of $I$ and $x$ as $i$ and $u_i$.

Comment: (vii) is a immediate consequence of (v) and (ii). Set $I = u$ and $u_i = i$, you can apply (v) because (ii) says $i\in I\in \mathcal{U}$ means $i \in \mathcal{U}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. $\mathcal U \subset P(\mathcal U)$ means that each element of $\mathcal U$ is also an element of $P(\mathcal U)$ in formulas $$\mathcal U \subset  P(\mathcal U) \iff \forall x\ (x \in \mathcal U \rightarrow x \subset \mathcal U)$$ since $x$ belongs to $P(\mathcal U)$ if and only if $x \subset \mathcal U$.
2. The proof of the (vii)-(x) it's really an easy exercise you should try to do yourself but I will give you some hints:

   - (ii)+(v) imply (vii)
   - (iv)+(ii) imply (ix)
   - (v)+(viii)+(iv) imply (x)

I am not entirely sure how to prove (viii) since this should depend on how have you defined the cartesian product, but once you know that it shouldn't be that difficult to prove it as well.

I hope this helps.